# what is the correct grant_type for foursquare oauth2 access

Tags: oauth-2.0, foursquare

what is the correct grant_type for foursquare oauth2 access?

I am using `grant_type=authorization_code`

but I keep getting `{"error":"invalid_grant"}`

Comment: And you specifying "response_type=code" in the initial request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"authorization_code" is the correct grant type (as specified @ https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth).

Your error message seems to be related do you having a bad/expired code, or specifying an incorrect client_id

Comment: so why is it saying invalid_grant?

Comment: because that's what the spec says to return in that event: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-5.2

Comment: It would have returned unsupported_grant_type if the grant_type value is not one of the supported ones.